# How to implement a custom exception?

Tags: java, eclipse, exception

This is my overTime excepton to print message if sales target isn't meet.

```
public class OverTimeException extends Exception {

        int salesTarget;
        public OverTimeException(int s) {
            salesTarget = s;
        }
        String myPrint()
        {

            return "exception caught because sales target is " + salesTarget; 


        }
    }
```

This is the Clerk class that I want to use the exception in salesTarget method.My question is how do I implement the exception into the salesTarget method?Thanks

```
public class Clerk extends Admin implements ClerkInterface {

    final double payRate = 13.00;
    final int salesTargetNum = 46;


    //Member variables
    private double unitSold;

    //Constructor
    public Clerk(String inName, String inId, double inHoursWorked,
            double intkPay, double inAdmin_quota,double inUnitSold) {
        super(inName, inId, inHoursWorked, intkPay, inAdmin_quota);

        setUnitSold(inUnitSold);

    }


    //setUnitsSold method
    private void setUnitSold(double inUnitSold) {
        unitSold = inUnitSold;

    }


    //getUnitsSold
    public double getUnitsSold(){

        return unitSold;
    }





    //toString method
    public String toString()
    {
        return " " + super.toString() + "Admin Quota " + getAdmin_quota() + "Units Sold" + getUnitsSold();


    }


    //method to confirm sales targets are made from ClerkInterface.
    public void salesTarget() {

        if(salesTargetNum >= unitSold){

            System.out.println("Clerk has not meet sales target");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Clerk has meet sales target");
        }

    }





    }//end Clerk
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where you want to throw the exception, simply do

```
throw new OverTimeException(salesTargetNum);
```

Comment: I tried this but it states that salesTarget cannot be resolved to a local variable,any ideas? thanks

Comment: The member you want to reference when throwing the exception is salesTargetNum, not salesTarget.

Comment: From where are you trying to throw the exception? Can you paste the code?

Comment: ya sure,    public void salesTarget()  {
  
  if(salesTargetNum >= unitSold){
   
   throw new OverTimeException(s);    
   
  }
  else
  {
   System.out.println("Clerk has meet sales target");
  }
  
 }

Comment: You're referencing the variable s from the salesTarget() method, but no such variable is currently in scope (i.e., s is not a local variable or an attribute of the Clerk class). I think you want to reference salesTargetNum, but I'm not sure. Perhaps you want to reference unitSold? Regardless, s definitely is wrong.

Comment: ok I figured out the variable salesTargetNum was a double that was problem.Thanks alot for the advice appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly recommend that you override *all* the constructors in the `Exception` class.

```
import java.lang.Exception;
import java.lang.String;
import java.lang.Throwable;

public class OvertimeException extends Exception {
    /**
     * Constructs a new exception with <code>null</code> as its detail message.
     * The cause is not initialized, and may subsequently be initialized by a
     * call to {@link #initCause}.
     */
    public OvertimeException() {
        super();    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a new exception with the specified cause and a detail
     * message of <tt>(cause==null ? null : cause.toString())</tt> (which
     * typically contains the class and detail message of <tt>cause</tt>).
     * This constructor is useful for exceptions that are little more than
     * wrappers for other throwables (for example, {@link
     * java.security.PrivilegedActionException}).
     * @param cause the cause (which is saved for later retrieval by the
     *              {@link #getCause()} method).  (A <tt>null</tt> value is
     *              permitted, and indicates that the cause is nonexistent or
     *              unknown.)
     * @since 1.4
     */
    public OvertimeException(Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a new exception with the specified detail message.  The
     * cause is not initialized, and may subsequently be initialized by
     * a call to {@link #initCause}.
     * @param message the detail message. The detail message is saved for
     *                later retrieval by the {@link #getMessage()} method.
     */
    public OvertimeException(String message) {
        super(message);    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a new exception with the specified detail message and
     * cause.  <p>Note that the detail message associated with
     * <code>cause</code> is <i>not</i> automatically incorporated in
     * this exception's detail message.
     * @param message the detail message (which is saved for later retrieval
     *                by the {@link #getMessage()} method).
     * @param cause   the cause (which is saved for later retrieval by the
     *                {@link #getCause()} method).  (A <tt>null</tt> value is
     *                permitted, and indicates that the cause is nonexistent or
     *                unknown.)
     * @since 1.4
     */
    public OvertimeException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(salesTargetNum >= unitSold){
    throw new OverTimeException(salesTarget);         
} else {
    System.out.println("Clerk has meet sales target");
}
```

And note that you need a `toString` method in your OverTimeException class rather than having `toPrint` method.

```
public class OverTimeException extends Exception {
    int salesTarget;
    public OverTimeException(int s) {
        salesTarget = s;
    } 
    public String toString() {  // Should be `toString`
        return "exception caught because sales target is " + salesTarget; 
    }
}
```

Also, add this exception in the `throws` clause of your `method declaration`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to

1. declare the exception in the method signature
2. throw that method when required

e.g.

```
public void salesTarget() throws OvertimeException{
   ...
   throws new OvertimeException(s);
}
```

Note that you don't need to declare [unchecked exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html) in the method signature.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 public void salesTarget() throws OverTimeException {
    if(salesTargetNum >= unitSold){
        throw new OverTimeException(salesTargetNum);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Clerk has meet sales target");
    }
}
```

And your exception should be declared like this.

```
public class OverTimeException extends Exception {

    public OvertimeException(int s){
        super("exception caught because sales target is " + s);
    }

}
```